# "data parameter is nil" Crashing AVPlayer on Network Loss

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, avplayer

I'll preface this by saying I'm on iOS 8, but I don't think it's an iOS 8 bug.

I'm using Apple's AVPlayer class to create a steaming music player. However, if I happen to lose connection, the app crashes with the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`. I realize this is probably because the AVPlayer is trying to play with an empty buffer, but I'm not sure a) how I can catch the exception or b) why this would cause a full-blown app crash. Is there some way to prevent this AVPlayer error from crashing the app on network loss? Thanks for the help!